# CSS: Sticky, Flex and Overflow

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, sticky

I've been looking around and i found out this is a well known situation when working with Sticky and Overflow but i still don't get a solution, might be because of the use of Flex too.

I have an aside with `display:Flex;` and `position:Sticky;` in my project and i'm trying to make it scrollable when the content overflows.

The whole webpage is structured with Grid and as i want the aside to ocuppy the full height of its column i gave it `flex:1;`

**HTML**

```
    <aside class="aside">
        <nav class="aside-menu">
                <ul class="aside-menu__ul">
                    <li class="aside-menu__li">title</li>
                    <li class="aside-menu__li"><img src="" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="aside-menu__li">description</li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
```

**CSS**

```
.aside{
        position: sticky;
        top:14%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        grid-row: 3 / 4;
        grid-column: 2 / 3;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 1;
}
```

Now, with this code when i scroll down the next happens:

[image]

The sticky isn't working at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your information is not enough, how height has you set for the grid, it appears to me that it is definitely not a particular number, right?
 So setting flex: 1 is not enough. The aside will take all the space it need. Sticky is working, but aside now is to long to see it. 
Try setting `height: 80vh;` to see the difference.

Comment: This works but, since we are giving a height to the aside, the main content of the different pages of the site is getting adapted to the height of the aside, not the aside adapting to the height of the main content.

Comment: That is why you need to set the height to the parent, in your case it the container that contains both the content and the aside. Then set the height of the aside 100%.